# Issues running a method asynchronously, and returning an object

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, android-asynctask

In my code I am reading from a json file in one class and needing it to return an object I created.

The object I entitled StockData (its a stock with symbol, name, price, etc..)

In page 2 I call a method from page 1 to 'getStockData()'.

The method looks similar to:

```
public async Task<StockData> getStockData()
        {
            string apiString = await apiConnection.DownloadStringTaskAsync(API);

            // ... important code is run ...
            // ... newStock is created as a  new StockData() type ...

            // returning newStock, which returns as a Task<StockData>
            return newStock;
        }
```

Unfortunately,  for obvious reasons, I cannot just return a StockData because an asynchronous method does not work that way.

However, on page two where the method is called from, I need to figure out some kind of way to convert it away from the task...

Here is an example of what I have on the other side:

```
StockData newStock = dm.getStockData();
```

Now I understand *why* its not working. So I don't need an explanation as to why my code isn't working. I just don't have a solution to get it to work.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work? Any work arounds or adjustments to my code I can do *while still allowing the method to run asynchronously?*

Many thanks ahead! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the await keyword?

```
StockData newStock = await dm.getStockData();
```

The operation will execute asynchronously and the return value will be of `StockData` type.

Comment: Perfect! that worked... Before I read your comment I was trying: .Result but that just kept freezing my app... Thanks a ton!

Comment: @AlzarTech: One way to think about it is that `async` "wraps" your value in a `Task<T>`, and `await` "unwraps" the value from `Task<T>`.